# Coxph reference level - dummy variable?

Tags: modeling, cox-model

In my experiment I had a treatment gradient with 3 levels. Where level 1 was assumed to be most toxic, level 2 less and level 3 even less. I used CoxPH in R and set level 3 as the reference treatment. 
Here arises the problem for me, I also want to compare level 3 with the other two levels and not just set the HR to 1. Because I'm also interested in 'how toxic' level 3 is compared with the other two levels. I have counted number of dead animals per level and time of death.

My thoughts on how to solve this:
Can I set a 'dummy' variable/level with 0 deaths as reference level?

Thank you in advance for helping me with this.

Answer (score 1):

If your observed values were numbers of dead animals rather than the times to death of individual animals, then a Cox model is not appropriate. A generalized linear model (e.g., binomial regression for dead/alive) is called for.

In any case, your main question still stands. A regression model with a multi-level categorical predictor contains the information needed for all comparisons among its levels. In outline, you use the covariance matrix of the coefficient estimates (provided by the model but often hidden from view; the `vcov()` function in R can display it) along with the formula for the [variance of a sum of correlated variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Sum_of_variables) and appropriate correction for [multiple comparisons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_comparisons_problem).

This process is simplified by software tools designed for post-modeling analysis. In R, the [`car` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=car) and the [`emmeans` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=emmeans) are often used for that.

With a simple model as you seem to have, just changing the reference level of the categorical predictor (and adjusting for multiple comparisons) would accomplish the same thing. It's wise to become familiar with the more general tools, as models aren't always so simple.

Comment: To clarify, I also registered time of death. And I have also used the Tukeys Post hoc analysis from the 'emmeans' package. But I wanted to know if I also could use a dummy variable for the cox analyses and get hazard ratios for all 3 levels.

Comment: @asellus that doesn't work for a Cox model as it doesn't have an intercept. What you can get are hazard ratios _between conditions_.  If "level 3" is reference then the coefficients/HRs for "level 1" and "level 2" say directly "'how toxic' level 3 is compared with the other two levels." To get the ratio between "level 1" and "level 2" you could specify one of them as the reference instead. If you want some absolute measure of mortality, use `survfit` or `predict` functions to evaluate differences in things like median survival time or differences in survival at specified times.